# Importing images and videos from photolibrary to a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, photo

Is it possible to import the images and the videos to a table view with all the complete information of the images and videos using imagepicker.....

Comment: yeah you can import them but the complete information means what?

Comment: details of the images and videos like name,size,etc....can u send me a sample to do this please....

Comment: hi @AjeyaSriharsha have you solved this problem? can you share the solution? :)